# How to get photos from my phone to my mac as quickly as possible?

Tags: macos, iphone, photos, data-synchronization, camera-roll

Right now, the answer would be airdrop as far as I am concerned.
I would just take a photo and press the share button and then wait for my laptop to come up.

However, I have an older phone and I find the share button to be quite slow to use.

Are there any apps or such that would allow me to take photos and send them to a folder on my mac without having to press anything?

Comment: Have you considered using Dropbox or something similar? This requires you to manually add photos to drop box but then they show up everywhere and the free version of Dropbox should do this quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Airdrop is best solutions for that but it's seems your MacBook unable to detect your iPhone because it's older version.
However in your MacBook there has an option under Airdrop like "Search for older device" you can use this option for older device to transfer your photos or you can use Image capture(through spotlight search)

Answer (score 0):

Surely iCloud is the answer? Either use My Photo Stream, which acts as a conduit from your phone to other devices, but doesn't store the photos long-term, or iCloud Photo Library, which does.

Or just connect your phone via USB and launch the Image Capture app, and transfer whatever you want.

Comment: It's not just a question of being automatic, though, I want to decide to take a photo of something and instantly be able to use that photo on my mac, as if I had taken the photo on the mac itself.